# Wordpress Header Logo resizing

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, image-resizing

I'm trying to resize the header's logo in my website www.cookingvinyls.com but I can't seem to overwrite the hardcoded version.

I've tried editing header.php with the basic width and height lines but it doesn't change a thing. I've also tried using Wordpress's quick CSS feature but the preview of the logo is never affected when I add any code lines.

Inspecting the logo area I get this:

```
<img class="main-logo" width="500" height="500" alt="Site Logo" 
src="//www.cookingvinyls.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Screen-Shot-
2018-02-14-at-13.35.06.png"
```

Does anyone have any tips?

Thanks!
A.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

```
img.main-logo {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
}
```

Too basic to be true... :)

Comment: If it still gives you trouble hit it with !important